# Why is the Diels-Alder reaction a syn addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

It is said that the Diels-Alder reaction is a syn-addition with respect to both the dienophile and the diene. Is there a reason for that!?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/adv.chem/lectures/lecture_17/node8.html

Of course there is a reason.

[image: HOMO of dien and LUMO of dienophile]

Interaction of these HOMO and LUMO is only possible as in the image, in a certain alignment which results in syn addition product.